# Unable to post QR Code Image on Facebook with swift

Tags: facebook, swift, uiimageview, qr-code, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am creating a QR Code reader application and once the QR Code Image is created then user can post it on faceBook.here is my code for It:

```
import UIKit
import Social
import MobileCoreServices

class NextViewController: UIViewController {

var userTextString : String?
@IBOutlet weak var QRCodeImage: UIImageView!
var tasteImage = UIImage(named: "Back.jpg")
@IBOutlet weak var userText: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Share", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "ShareIt")
    self.userText.text = self.userTextString
    var qrText = self.userTextString
    CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
    self.QRCodeImage.image = {
        var qrCode = QRCode("\(qrText)")!
        qrCode.size = self.QRCodeImage.bounds.size
        return qrCode.image
        }()
}

func ShareIt(){

            var activityIteams : [AnyObject]?

            if QRCodeImage.image != nil{
                activityIteams = [userText.text as String!, self.QRCodeImage.image as UIImage!]
            }else{
                activityIteams = [userText.text as String!]
            }
            println(activityIteams)
            let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityIteams!, applicationActivities: nil)
            self.presentViewController(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
}
```

But I can not post anything on Facebook with this code and if I try to post only text then it works but with image its not working and I got this in console:

```
2015-03-04 16:45:18.128 testing[11389:160922] plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post interrupted
```

And If I try another Image which is already stored into project, I can easily post that on facebook But I don't know what is wrong with my QR Code Image.

Here is my sample project for more Information.

https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/QR-Code

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution something like this way:

First I save the Image to Document Directory and then I retrieve that Image From that Directory and It works fine for Me here Is my Updated Code.

```
import UIKit
import Social
import MobileCoreServices

class QRImage: UIViewController {

var userTextString : String?
@IBOutlet weak var QRCodeImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var userText: UILabel!
var imageView = UIImageView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Share", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "ShareIt")
    self.userText.text = self.userTextString
    var qrText = self.userTextString
    CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)

    self.QRCodeImage.image = {
        var qrCode = QRCode("\(qrText)")!
        qrCode.size = self.QRCodeImage.bounds.size

        return qrCode.image
        }()
    self.createThumBil()
}

func ShareIt(){

    var activityIteams : [AnyObject]?

        if QRCodeImage.image != nil{
            activityIteams = [userText.text as String!, self.imageView.image as UIImage!]
        }else{
            activityIteams = [userText.text as String!]
        }
        println(activityIteams)
        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityIteams!, applicationActivities: nil)
        self.presentViewController(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func getImage(){

    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let getImagePath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("QRCode.png")
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: getImagePath)
}

func createThumBil(){

    let originalImage : UIImage = self.QRCodeImage.image!
    let destinationSize : CGSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize)
    originalImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, destinationSize.width, destinationSize.height))
    let newImage : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    let thumbNailimageData : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage)
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    if let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) {
        if paths.count > 0 {
            if let dirPath = paths[0] as? String {
                println(dirPath)
                thumbNailimageData.writeToFile(dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("QRCode.png"), atomically: true)
            }
        }
    }
    self.getImage()
    }
}
```